# flight-offers-search and flight-cheapest-date-search - limit by number of connections and layover duration

Tags: amadeus

I am testing **flight-offers-search** and **flight-cheapest-date-search**
Are there parameters available to limit by number of connections and layover duration, didn't see it in the doc.

Also, is there a functionality to fetch future prices for given period ex: get average price for 2 week trips in the next month, 3 months, 1 year?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first point: In the Flight Offers Search API: As of today, the API doesn't offer a parameter to control the time of the layover you will have to check the response and do it on your side. For the number of connections, you can filter direct and non-direct flights using the parameter `nonStop`. Then, if you want to limit the number of stops you have to do it by filtering the response (by looking at the number of `segments` inside the `itineraries`).

Flight Cheapest Date Search has a similar parameter to control the direct and non-direct offers: `nonStop`.

Regarding your second point: not directly, for this, you can do it by:

- Use the Flight Offers Search and do multiples searches and make an average of the prices you find
- Use the Flight Cheapest Date Search to do the same (keep in mind that this API uses a pre-computed cache and has a limited number of origin-destination)